# Decorator pattern method calls

Tags: php, oop, decorator

I've been trying to learn the Decorator pattern off a video on YouTube. I'm a little confused by something that is probably elementary OOP.

In the code below I make one method call (see bottom of code) to  $p->getDescription();

This returns a concatenated string built up from all of the classes created in $p = new cheese(new sauce(new plainPizza));

But when I run get_class($p)  its the cheese class.  So how does a method call on the cheese class (i.e. $p->getDescription()) propagate through all of the classes?  Why doesn't it just call the cheese class' getDescription method?

```
<?php

interface Pizza{

    public function getDescription();
    public function getCost();
}


class plainPizza implements Pizza{

    public function getDescription(){
        return 'Thin dough ';
    }

    public function getCost(){
        return 4;
    }
}

abstract class ToppingDecorator implements Pizza{

    protected $pizza;

    public function __construct(Pizza $pizza){
        $this->pizza = $pizza;
    }
}

class cheese extends ToppingDecorator{

    public function __construct(Pizza $pizza){
        parent::__construct($pizza);
    }

    public function getDescription(){
        return $this->pizza->getDescription() . ' and adding cheeeeeese!';

    }

    public function getCost(){
        return $this->pizza->getCost() + 0.55;
    }

}



class sauce extends ToppingDecorator{

    public function __construct(Pizza $pizza){
        parent::__construct($pizza);    
    }

    public function getDescription(){
        return $this->pizza->getDescription() . ' and adding sauce ';
    }

    public function getCost(){
        return $this->pizza->getCost() + 1.25;
    }

}


$p = new cheese(new sauce(new plainPizza));

echo '<br>';
echo $p->getDescription(); //return Thin dough and adding sauce and adding cheeeeeese!
echo '<br>';
echo get_class($p); //return cheese
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the whole point of the decorator pattern. Each outer class "decorates" its inner class by adding on or modifying its methods. In this instance, the getDescription method of each class adds its little bit to the getDescription method of the class it decorates.

The outer decorator is **cheese**, its inner decorator is **sauce**, which in turn decorates **pizza**. So when **cheese**'->getDescription() is called, it calls **sauce**'s getDescription() method which calls **pizza**'s getDescription() method.

As you can see in the sauce and cheese classes, the getDescription method calls the wrapped class's get description method before adding its own bit to the send and returning it..

```
 public function getDescription(){
        return $this->pizza->getDescription() . ' and adding sauce ';
    }
```

That is how all the getDescription methods are called by **cheese**'s.

Comment: Thanks for the response dbugger. I'm still a tad confused. By what mechanism do all of the getDesceiption methods get called? Since only the cheese classes' method is explicitly called what makes it cascade through all the other classes? Sorry if I'm being slow just really keen to understand what's going on in more detail than what I can observe.

Comment: There is no magic mechanism, follow the code. Look at the getDescription() method for **cheese**. What's the first thing that method does?  It calls the getDescription method of **sauce**.  What's the first thing that method does? It calls the getDescription method of **pizza**. It might help to understand if you add logging.

Comment: Thanks dbugger the penny actually dropped from your last comment. Looking at it now I can see that cheese getDescription cannot return until it's pizza object getDeacription returns and so on... Thanks for taking the time to clarify.